# DDIM scheduler scaling the denoising model input depending on the current timestep

Tags: diffusion-models

I can't find any resources on scaling the denoising model input depending on the current timestep for diffusion models. Just briefly mentioned in the appendix of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.02502.pdf) , but not much more. Does anyone have a source on a comparison of doing vs omitting it?

Here's the [huggingface diffusers implementation](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/v0.8.0/en/api/schedulers#diffusers.DDIMScheduler.scale_model_input)